# Error initialising firebase in golang app

Tags: firebase, go

I am using firebase go sdk (https://github.com/acoshift/go-firebase-admin) and have followed the docs to set up my app.

But when I try to initialize the app with `firebase.NewApp` I get an error saying

> google: could not find default credentials.

Can someone please help

Here is the code snippet

```
opt = option.WithCredentialsFile(viper.GetString("firebase"))
app, err = firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), nil, opt)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error initializing app: %v\n", err)
}
```

Comment: try https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in `opt = option.WithCredentialsFile(viper.GetString("firebase"))`
It couldn't find the path to your config file. Try to use path to file and then find how to add it via viper